# preg_replace find and replace with appended value

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$string = 'img-file_name.jpg';
$pattern = '\.\w+';
$replacement = '_small$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I want to append _small to the end of the file, just before the . extension

I want the final result to be: img-file_name_small.jpg

> Receiving error: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

(it refers to last line, `echo preg_replace ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex:

```
$string = 'img-file_name.jpg';
$replacement = '_small';
$p = pathinfo($string);
echo $p['filename'].$replacement.$p['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is missing a correct [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) - as the error message tells you.

`$pattern = '/\.\w+/';` works, as does e.g. `$pattern = '#\.\w+#';`

But for this pattern to work, you need to define the extension as a group (at the moment you will miss the extension in the result).

```
$pattern = '#(\.\w+)#';
```

Only now you are able to use `$1` to reference back to the pattern